# JQuery function to validate multinational telephone numbers

Tags: jquery, validation

I have a form which asks the customer for a telephone number. I am trying to add some form of validation client-side to ensure we only get valid numbers coming through.

Currently I've set up a test form to try out different scripts. Currently I've got:

```
    <form id="myForm">
    <lable for="telephone">Telephone:</label><br>
    <input type="tel" id="telephone" name="telephone" data-validation-url="/validate.js"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">

    </form>
```

And for the Validation I've got a separate validation.js file with the following code:

```
var reg =  /^((\+44\s?|0)7([45789]\d{2}|624)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})$/ ; //UK phone regex 
      function PhoneValidation(telephone)
      {  
       
        var OK = reg.exec(telephone);  
        if (!OK)  
          window.alert("phone number isn't  valid");  
        else  
          window.alert("phone number is  valid");  
      }
```

The plan is to have a different regex for each country we cover. Unless there is a simpler and tidier way to do this.

Now my issue is, the validation doesn't actually work. It doesn't show an alert when an invalid number is put in.
I've checked the regex on regex101.com and this is the correct regex so I know it isn't that.
Hopefully someone could shed some light on why this isn't working? Knowing me it'll be something simple I'm overlooking!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not use the jQuery Validate tag when your question has absolutely nothing to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.  This would be tag-spam.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve this by adding an onClick() function on the submit button triggering the validation function.